# docker pull always show "Already exists" for layers during pull even after deleting all images

Tags: docker

here is my input and output:

```
shshenhx@shshenhx:~/Desktop/Docker$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
python              latest              336d482502ab        4 days ago          692 MB

shshenhx@shshenhx:~/Desktop/Docker$ docker rmi 336
Untagged: python:latest
Untagged: python@sha256:bf0718e2882cabc144c9c07d758b09c65efc104a6ddc72a9a976f8b26f67c2ee
Deleted: sha256:336d482502ab564b0b2964b2ed037529ba40c7b4ade2117ca11d74edbf11f99e
Deleted: sha256:1e2f72b0bf844de7bfe57a32115b660770355843ef8078fb55629e720147e6a9
Deleted: sha256:b5818ba96f33835318f3e9d7b4094e1007be247f04ab931ea9ef83b45b451f90
Deleted: sha256:0c2d7cafdab1084ebbd0112b3bedf76458ae6809686fb0ad9bae8022f11c3a84

shshenhx@shshenhx:~/Desktop/Docker$ docker pull python
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/python
4176fe04cefe: Already exists 
851356ecf618: Already exists 
6115379c7b49: Already exists 
aaf7d781d601: Already exists 
40cf661a3cc4: Already exists 
975fe2fd635f: Pull complete 
bf4db784e7fd: Pull complete 
0491f7e9426b: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:bf0718e2882cabc144c9c07d758b09c65efc104a6ddc72a9a976f8b26f67c2ee
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:latest
```

My question is, I have already rm python image, why it still shows already exist for some of layers? How can I totally delete all the python layers. 
Thanks.

Comment: is there any container running? docker container ls

Comment: What does `docker images -a` show after the `docker rmi`?

Comment: I am having this same issue (if I understand the thread title correctly). If I run `docker container ls -a` or `docker images -a` after running `docker system prune -a`, both will show 0 containers/images,. Then if I do, `docker pull ubuntu` all layers but the last show "_Already exists_". There should be a way to hard reset everything.

Answer (score 4):

What helped for me was to run `docker-system prune` after removing all containers and images. So the whole process I got it to work was:

1. Remove all containers `docker rm -vf $(docker ps -a -q)`
2. Remove all images `docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)`
3. **Prune system**  with `docker system prune`

Comment: The steps above are not working as of Apr 11, 2022, docker version `20.10.7` , on Ubuntu `20.04 LTS`

Answer (score 3):

From [reference of docker images command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#options)

> Docker images have intermediate layers that increase reusability, decrease 
>       disk usage, and speed up docker build by allowing each step to be cached. 
>       These intermediate layers are not shown by default.

Maybe those `Already exists` are intermediate layers. By default, they are hided when you run `docker images`, please try `docker images --all`.

Answer (score 3):

`docker system prune -a` helped me.It will remove both unused and dangling images.

Answer (score 3):

For someone interested in: (1) using the command line; (2) removing cache only for images that have been removed with `docker rmi` (i.e., not visible with `docker images --all`), but for which caches are still present, and for which the `Already exists` shows for layers when pulling image; you can try this command:

```
docker builder prune
```

(It may take up to 15 minutes to run this command, so be patient.)

This command seems to have solved the problem for me. I did not want to use the general, "system-wide" `prune` / `purge` / clean docker commands and functionalities, because I had some images and containers running (not related to the image that I have already removed), that I wished to have left as they were.

Source of the solution: https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-delete-cache/5753/7

I think that the situation of "invisible" cached layers for images removed with `docker rmi` may happen due to the fact of using docker compose (as suggested also by John Doe in his comment to one of the answers in the current question: [docker pull always show "Already exists" for layers during pull even after deleting all images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920984/docker-pull-always-show-already-exists-for-layers-during-pull-even-after-delet#comment128143891_64344868)).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `docker system prune` but it will clear everything in docker.
Its not an image problem its actually cache problem so deleting your images wont work because the problem relies in layer caching.
There is a --no-cache flag in docker build but I don't know if it works with docker pull too.

Answer (score 1):

Docker has a solution for this on docker dashboard, just press the button below and presto it works! (This is in the troubleshooting section. or the bug icon)
[image: purge data]

Comment: Docker dashboard exists only in Docker Desktop version. This method is impossible on linux

Comment: yeah, but for the people who are stuck and spend 3 hours looking for a solution to this infuriating bug can fix it. Sure it does not solve everyones issues, but the solution is no where on the internets, trust me I have looked.

Comment: At least you need to mention that this will work only for Docker Desktop(macOS and Windows)

Comment: This appears to be the only way to delete corrupted cached images in docker-compose, good catch.

Answer (score 1):

There is a docker command that deletes images that do not have an associated running container:

- `docker image prune`
  allows you to clean up dangling images (a dangling image is not tagged and not referenced by any container)
- `docker image prune -a`
  will remove all images that are not used by any existing containers
- `docker image prune -a --filter "until=48h"`
  you can add a filter (--filter) to limit the images to be pruned, as in this example, only images that are older than 48 hours

You can add the -f or --force flag to prune the images and not prompt for confirmation

You could use this in a scheduled bash script to keep your drive tidy

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of searching, I have a *solution* although I don't think it's necessarily a great one.

The "sledge hammer solution" would be to do:

```sh
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

This basically factory resets docker, so you would lose everything. This was fine for my case, but ***be very careful and think this through before using this one.***

Answer (score -1):

Please try this command `docker rmi 336d482502ab` and then try to pull it again.

Comment: The shortened prefix `336` does the same thing, as long as there isn't any ambiguity with more than one image

Comment: yes, I knew we can remove by the prefix of image id, but I would like to ask him to try again with full image id.

Comment: The full image id is `336d482502ab564b0b2964b2ed037529ba40c7b4ade2117ca11d74edbf11f99e`. `336d482502ab` is also a short prefix.